# connect two pcs per lan

Tags: subnet, opensuse

I have four PC´s, all of which have a OpenSuse 42.3 OS and are connected with a Lan wire. I now want to communicate with one Server-PC to the other three.

I already gave all of them a Subnetmask of /24.
PC-Server IP: 192.186.17.1 Hostname: S1
PC-Client1 IP: 192.168.17.2  Hostname: C1 
... 
PC-Client3 IP: 192.168.17.4 Hostname: C3
Then i wrote "192.168.17.2 C1" in /etc/hosts of PC-Server as well as "192.168.17.2 S1" in PC-Client1.

I have also set the gateway of all Clientsw to the IP of the PC-Server.

If i try to "ping" from one PC to another i get the failure message "destination host unreachable".

I assume my domain configuration is wrong but i dont know much about that. What should i do?

Comment: Did you forget to enable forwarding?

Comment: Why would you enable forwarding for L2 communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to clarify what your network looks like.

[image]

Second test that your connections work, so from C1 ping the other clients and server. We are assuming you have given your clients and server a correct network configuration as shown in the diagram.

- ping 192.168.17.2
- ping 192.168.17.3
- ping 192.168.17.4

If all that works edit /etc/hosts on C1 and add

```
192.168.17.2 C2
192.168.17.3 C3
192.168.17.4 S1
```

- ping C2
- ping C3
- ping S1

If all that works, continue doing the same for the other hosts.

You dont need to set the gateway for C1, C2 and C3 to test local L2 communications.

If you still have trouble, you need to show content of `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ip route` from C1 and C2

When troubleshoting network problems ask yourself

1. Does the physical connection work?
2. Does L2 work? (MAC)
3. Does L3 work? (IP)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now i have another question. I want to edit the local network in a way that takes the server as gateway towards the internet, meaning that C1 asks S1 for Internetaccess, S1 allows it and acts as a middlemen between the Internet and C1. How can i do that exactly?

Comment: An easy way to do this is to take an old laptop or pretty much any other equipment and install ubuntu server, than install shorewall (wrapper for iptables) and create a router / firewall configuration. Also the easiest way is to have two physical interfaces, so i use USB to RJ-45 myself. If your create a question and link it i will gladly give my suggestion to how you can solve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is the link: "https://serverfault.com/questions/910403/how-can-i-set-up-a-pc-as-gateway-from-a-local-network-to-the-internet"