# How can i set up a PC as gateway from a local network to the internet?

Tags: networking, subnet, opensuse

This is a follow up question to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/909969/connect-two-pcs-per-lan) question.

I want to configue a local network in a way that its clients use a server as gateway towards the internet.

The OS on all clients and the server is OpenSuse 42.3. Every member can already access the internet by it self and every member is able to ping towards every other.

I gave the server two IP´s: one for the local network and one for the internet and enabled ipv4 forwarding within.

The clients use the IP of the server as standart gateway towards the internet but i probably set some values wrong, since it dosent work.

Comment: You must enable `ip_forward`, and create a NAT rule on iptables. _Does not work_ needs more details: error messages, tests you done, unexpected behavior...

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSuse should have the shorewall and shorewall-doc packages available from it's package manager.

https://software.opensuse.org/package/shorewall

> The Shoreline Firewall, more commonly known as "Shorewall", is a Netfilter > (iptables) based firewall that can be used on a dedicated firewall system, > a multi-function gateway/ router/server or on a standalone GNU/Linux system.

Debian Example

After installing shorewall enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and execute `sysctl -p`

Assuming you have two ethernet interfaces on your gateway and you have installed shorewall-doc, we want the following examples from /usr/share/doc/shorewall/examples/two-interfaces/

- zones

  - Tells shorewall what zones (networks) is attached to it.
- interfaces

  - Tells shorewall what interfaces it can use
- masq

  - Translate our private IP address range to our public IP
- policy

  - Makes broad and wide changes
- rules

  - Makes exception to the policy file

And place them all in /etc/shorewall/

**Zones file** should contain

- fw firewall
- net ipv4
- loc ipv4

Here is an example **interfaces file**, the dhcp option on eth0 is for if you get a 'dynamic' static address from your ISP.

```
net     eth0            dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,sourceroute=0
loc     eth1            tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians
```

Your masq file translates your private address range to your public address, example

```
eth0                    192.168.1.0/24
```

The **policy file** is for broad and dramatic firewall changes, and here it's normal to

1. Deny all incoming traffic
2. Allow all outgoing traffic

Policy example

```
loc net ACCEPT
fw all DROP
net all DROP
all all DROP
```

The **rules file** makes exceptions for the policy file, so here we for example want to allow SSH to the gateway because `all all DROP` should otherwise deny us to send any packages to the FW

```
SSH(ACCEPT)     loc     $FW
```

Allow ICMP packages so we dont deny ICMP PMTU.

```
ACCEPT          all     all     icmp
```

Allow the firewall to resolve DNS queries, because this is blocked in the policy. on Debian used to run apt-get update and install packages.

```
ACCEPT  $FW     net     tcp,udp         53,80
```

http://shorewall.net/manpages/ is really well documented for all the options above.

Before you take your firewall rules in use, check that the configuration is without errors by using `shorewall check` and make the new changes take effect with `shorewall safe-restart`

When you have created a configuration that works and you are happy with save your iptables rules with `iptables-save > /root/iptables.txt` and make an entry in /etc/network/interfaces to load the rules before your interfaces comes up `pre-up iptables-restore < /root/iptables.txt` so if shorewall at some point failes to start, your network wont be defenseless.

Their are more to do, to further harden your network but this is a start.